Solenoid coil repairing
My change over JQX-62F-2Z relay coil burns.
So I want to repair the coil.
Please guide me about wire gauge and turns to repair my relay coil.

That’s something you’ll need to figure out. You can measure the wire gauge and count the number of turns or at least estimate the total wire length. Most would just replace the failed unit.

Coil totally burns so can not count the turns. And second the wire gauge how can measures because coil burns but one thing that heve seen the wire is too much thin.

I want to make it repaired for ac 220 magnetic coil.

Complicated (?), except if you "know". You should buy another ...

The manufacturer does not intend for the relay to be repaired and does not publish the information you seek. You will have to determine that information yourself.

if it helps, an AC-driven relay coil may overheat if the armature does not close properly - it improves the magnetic circuit, increasing the inductance and so reducing the current. Just rewinding the coil (just!) will not be sufficient if the armature movement is the problem.

I’m voting to close this question because there is no way for someone who doesn't have the relay to know the turns.

This is not something you can repair – the relay needs to be replaced. I didn't know that reason myself, but as Neil_UK points out in the comments, this could be a mechanical failure, leading to an electrical failure. Repairing the electrical failure will not fix the relay.
Furthermore, this is a relay. It's not expensive, quite the contrary, but it's probably critical in the sense that unreliable contacting means large currents heat up things beyond what they should be. Or worse, it's safety-critical and the relay not switching when it should would leave something energized that might lead to damage or injuries.
There's literally no reasonable way to repair this from hand to a degree that I'd argue is satisfactory. You link to a Spanish product page (.es) – so I'll assume you're in Spain. You should be able to get a new relay there by tomorrow or Wednesday, depending on what you pay for delivery. There's really no point in doing hazardous repairs.
